# Angular 4 - TinyMCE image upload

Tags: angular, tinymce, image-uploading

In my Angular 4 app I was unable to make any image upload work inside of TinyMCE. The general image plugin is not working properly. I would be happy with very [simple upload window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0BDf.png) if I could specify POST URL ( + would prefer application/octet-stream' but form would be ok as well).

I have successfully used 
 [ng2-file-upload](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload) in my app already but TinyMCE doesn't support typescript so I was unable to use it there.

Anyone who was successful with implementing image upload for TinyMCE with Angular 4?

Comment: `"I have successfully used ng2-file-upload in my app already but TinyMCE doesn't support typescript so I was unable to use it there."` - TinyMCE runs in the browser and no browser can actually run TypeScript.  It would all be compiled to JavaScript before getting delivered to the web browser.

Comment: @MichaelFromin What I meant by that is that I cannot just use custom button and in editor.windowManager.open under html: use Angular and utilize typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to find a way how to use ng2-file-upload in the end. Following code is part of Editor component where I define stuff for tinyMCE. I will only show most imporant parts.

HTML:

```
<textarea id="{{elementId}}"></textarea>
<input id='input' type="file" #fileInput ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploadFile.uploader" style="display: none;"
       accept="image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg"/>
```

Typescript:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.uploadFile.uploader.onCompleteItem = (item: any, response: string, status: any, headers: any) => {
     ....
          tinymce.activeEditor.insertContent('<img src="' + location + '"/>');
....
    };
  }

ngAfterViewInit() {

    tinymce.init({
.....
setup: editor => {
        this.editor = editor;
        editor.on('keyup', () => {
          const content = editor.getContent();
          this.onEditorKeyup.emit(content);
        });
        editor.on('reset', function(e) {
          editor.setContent('');
        });
        editor.addButton('mybutton', {
          text: 'Image',
          icon: 'image',
          onclick: function() {
            var input = document.getElementById('input');
            input.click();
          }
        });
      },
.....
}
```

It is not very fancy, just opens file picker on click and then uploads (need to set uploader to autoupload) but it is enough for me.